# Data validation for numbers in Google Sheets not working

Tags: validation, google-sheets, numbers

In Google Sheets, I set the data validation of a cell to a number that must be greater than or equal to 100. When I enter 9999999999999999999999, I get an error that the entered value must be greater than or equal to 100. Why does this happen? I also tried to change the formats to no avail.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyMyt.png) | [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1W82.png) | [Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eEWR.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Sheets (and spreadsheets in general) store numbers with 15 digits of precision. The reason why has to do with how numbers are stored in computer hardware. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 for an explanation.

When you enter a number like 9999999999999999999999, Google Sheets treats it like a string. If sheets tried to treat it like a number, it would actually be rounded to 1E22 (the last 8 digits are rounded off).

Comment: Ohhhhhh. That makes sense. Thank you so much! I found a way around it by using the custom formula "=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(E2:E), "^[0-9]{19,}$")".